# Robolectric - ShadowCanvas - NullPointerException on InvocationPlan.toString()

Tags: android, reflection, robolectric

When trying to execute ShadowCanvas.getHeight(), I get a NullPointerException in ShadowWrangler.InvocationPlan.toString()

My app code:

```
public float getCanvasHeight() {
    return mCanvas.getHeight();
}
```

Throws exception:

> Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot
>   evaluate
>   com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$InvocationPlan.toString()

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this shows up in your debugger but doesn't get thrown when you actually run the code?

The debugger probably calls toString() when showing the variables, and some value used in the implementation of toString() isn't yet initialized. So instead of showing you the string of the contents, it shows this exception.

Unless you actually call toString() in the code this exception wouldn't be thrown at runtime, although the uninitialized value could be an issue somewhere else.